# Getting "Critical Error: Your Start menu isn't working" in Windows when pressing the Start Menu

Tags: windows, windows-10, partitioning

My problem is that whenever I try to access the start menu or the search dialog, an error message pops, stating "Critical Error: Your Start menu isn't working".

Some background information:
I initially installed Windows (10) alongside Ubuntu as dual boot, which worked great for some time. Today I decided to stick to windows only, and wanted to delete Ubuntu to free more space for the C: partition.
So I booted into a live cd, deleted the Ubuntu-related partitions and did the following:
    1. Moved the windows recovery partition (I think this is what it was, very small sized) to the end of the hard drive
    2. Extended the C: drive to the now free space adjacent to it.

I did it with the unix gparted utility. When it run, all operations went smoothly besides the C: drive resizing. The gparted log can be found here: https://pastebin.com/yTgKG2ve
At the bottom of the failure report, it says "ERROR: NTFS is inconsistent. Run chkdsk /f on Windows then reboot it TWICE!"

Then I restarted, booted into Windows, and the Start Menu error occurred. I tried running `chkdsk /f` as the failure report adviced, then restarted twice but it didn't help.
I then tried running `chkdsk /r`, and when restarting it got stuck in the "Scanning and repairing drive C:" screen on 11%.
I then tried (following this guide: https://www.easeus.com/resource/stuck-at-scanning-and-repairing-drive.html) up until (including) method 3, which didn't help.
Then I booted into auto repair mode (or something like that?), which failed. I logged into safe mode, which after restart allowed me to boot into windows, though the Start Menu error still consists.

I also tried logging into a different user, though I have no other user and the "add user" button in the settings doesn't do anything...

It is worth mentioning that I am able to launch cmd.exe when in Windows.

Does anyone by chance have an idea of what happened? How can I fix this?

Thanks!
BTW, sorry for the long description :P...